# Is there a way to turn on stdout and stderr for MSTSC to log?

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-desktop

E.g., for `remote-viewer` and `xfreerdp` apps, they print some info to their stdout and stderr. Also, I can use their special cmd flags like `--debug` or `/log-level:debug` to get even more information. So, I can read their stdout and stderr to and write them to a log file for a future investigation, etc.

It looks like `mstsc.exe` (when run out of a command line) is always completely mute and I found no options to change this. Is it as it is, or do I miss something? Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done this way:

Go to `Start`->`Control Panel` -> `Administrative Tools` -> `Event Viewer` -> `Application and Services Logs` -> `Microsoft` -> `Windows` -> `TerminalServices - ClientActiveXCore` -> `Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational`. I found it [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJesS49e8cs).

There, when you launch `mstsc` -- no matter via a cmd or via GUI - you will get runtime log events about connecting, disconnecting, etc.

There is API to fetch the logs (e.g. run out of `cmd.exe`):

```
wevtutil query-events Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RDPClient/Operational
```

This can be done programmatically via [Event Logging API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/) or [Windows Event Log API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/). Not sure which one -- I have not tried it out yet. I discovered this info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48698203/how-to-open-windows-service-specific-event-log). It looks like the latter variant should work, but it is only supported since Vista. So maybe, it is better to give a try with the former one first.